# Font size of Chapter number and Chapter Title

Tags: titles, chapters, fontsize, report

As in the picture below I want to change the font size of Chapter number "Chapter 1" and title "Introduction" separately. Is there any way I can do that. I have used the package `sectsty` but it changed the size of both. I need "Chapter 1" smaller than the title "Introduction".

[image]

Comment: Standard class set chapter 1 huge  so it's smaller than introduction Huge. So what is your class?

Comment: I am using report.

Answer (score 9):

`report.cls` class use `\huge` for chapter 1 and `\Huge` for introduction. The problem is that with `\documentclass{report}` normal fontsize is 10pt and `\Huge=\huge` if you set `\documentclass[11pt]{report}` you'll see that's differts. you can use `sectsty` package like this

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\tiny} 
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}




\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont%
    \huge% %change this size to your needs for the first line
    \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{%
    \Huge %change this size to your needs for the second line
    }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me one more thing. How can I put the title (and chapter number) in the center of the page?

Comment: @MrSingh: replace `{\normalfont%` with `{\normalfont\filcenter%` in  LaRiFaRi's code.