# How to set the chapter, section, and default text to specific proportion widths?

Tags: fonts, titles, chapters, fontsize

I have the following MVP:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
}
\setmainfont{MyMonospaceFont}
\newlength{\characterwidth}
\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}
\geometry{margin=0.7in,textwidth=96\characterwidth,lines=48}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{3\characterwidth}}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\title{xyz}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section*{A}
hello world
\section*{B}
\section*{C}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

I would like for the *default* font character width to be let's say 12pt, and then have the section width be 18pt, and the chapter be 24pt. Or perhaps 12pt 24pt 48pt. But in either case, I'm wondering how to do it.

I looked at these places:

- [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti)
- [Font size of Chapter number and Chapter Title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255425/font-size-of-chapter-number-and-chapter-title)
- [How to change section/subsection font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103286/how-to-change-section-subsection-font-size)

But they don't go far enough into answer it and I'm stuck. For example, they explain `\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}`, but not how to use `48pt` there, like `\chaptertitlefont{48pt}` just shows up as `48ptFoo`. I've run into many issues with the answers, so wondering if one could help.

Comment: I think this should steer you in the right direction:
[Specify font point size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/latex-specify-font-point-size)

Comment: `\\fontsize{48pt}{60pt}\selectfont`  in `\titleformat` (from `titlesec`) should to the trick.

Comment: @Bernard, even for a monospaced font?

Comment: @Bernard `\titleformat*{\chapter}{\fontsize{48pt}{60pt}\selectfont}` or `\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{48pt}{60pt}\selectfont}` don't have any effect on the corresponding text.

Comment: Try with `\titleformat` (without  *) which requires `5` arguments.

Comment: I have no idea, not working `\titleformat{\section}[display]{\fontsize{6mm}{12mm}\selectfont}{}{}`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are loading sectsty you can use its commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros} %adapt
\newlength{\characterwidth}
\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}
\geometry{margin=0.7in,textwidth=96\characterwidth,lines=48}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{3\characterwidth}}
\frenchspacing

\chapterfont{\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\selectfont} %<---
\sectionfont{\fontsize{18pt}{24pt}\selectfont} %<---
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section*{A}
hello world
\section*{B}
\section*{C}
\end{document}
```