Absolute font size in chapter title
To make my chapter title have smaller font than the default (\huge) I tried \chapter{\LARGE Chapter Name} which got the text very close to the size I wanted (\large was smaller than I wanted).  To get a more exact measurement I tried both \chapter{\fontsize{20pt} Chapter Name} and \chapter{\fontsize{20} Chapter Name} but they won't compile.  Does anyone know how to do this in a way that will compile?  (If it matters I'm using the book class.)

You should never have font changes in the argument, just adjust the definition in the preamble, but \fontsize takes two arguments, font and baselineskip and requires \selectfont  to follow to select the font

This seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/727607 do you want to delete that one?

Have a look at packages like titlesec which allow you to adjust the format of your chapter titles.

For a correct and consistent change of the font size of chapter headings see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255425/font-size-of-chapter-number-and-chapter-title and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/how-to-adjust-the-size-and-placement-of-chapter-heading-in-report-class.

For the usage of \fontsize see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148508/how-does-fontsize-work and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322256/what-is-the-second-value-in-fontsize-for

\fontsize takes two arguments, and sets the font size and baseline spacing. so you have
\fontsize{20} C

so sets the baselineskip to C which generates the missing number error.
To actually select a font after changing the font settings you then need \selectfont.
You should however never use font changes in the argument of a section heading like \chapter. As well as breaking the consistent document design, the font will also be used in the page head and table of contents where a 20pt font would be totally unsuitable.
The definition from book but changing \Huge is
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    %\Huge
    \fontsize{20pt}{22pt}\selectfont
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


Thanks for answering.  I got around the Table of Contents issue with \chapter[toc version]{\large Chapter Name} which keeps the TOC size the same regardless of the size on the page.  I'm just amazed how complicated such a seemingly simple command has to be.

Using the optional argument as we showed in comments on your original question hides some of the worst aspects but using a font change there is still wrong, there is no reason for latex to makevthat simple, although it's hard to see how it could be simpler, your problem was unrelated to sectioning, just a syntax error with fontsize. @Nate
